# Possible to connect to an azure event hub through a browser and websockets?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, websocket, azure-eventhub

I'm trying to implement a web based chat program, my plan is to update an azure cosmos database with chat messages, then push an event to an azure event hub.

The missing element is for connected web browsers to receive these events.

I tried using the azure event hubs npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/event-hubs) but that looks like it's server side.

Is there a way to accomplish this without having to spin up some sort of server or service?

Comment: Event hub does not seem a logical choice for this. Try Azure signalr

Comment: @PeterBons, can you provide a solution, so we can learn from it? Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to diectly connect EventHub via a browser with websocket, as I known, the only way to realize it is to use AMQP over WebSocket to connect EventHub.

There is a MSDN blog introduce this topic [`Connect to Azure Event Hub in browser ( using AMQP over WebSockets )`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zhiqing/2017/03/16/connect-to-azure-event-hub-in-browser-using-amqp-over-websockets/), and the other blog of the same author introduce [`How to use AMQP protocol in Browser (JavaScript)`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zhiqing/2017/03/28/how-to-use-amqp-protocol-in-browser-javascript/). And you can get `rhea.js` from its GitHub repo `https://github.com/amqp/rhea/tree/master/dist`.

Meanwhile, according to the information from the source codes of `@azure/event-hubs`, it seems to support the feature of AMQP over WebSocket in browser, as the figure below comes from the source code https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/event-hubs/src/impl/eventHubClient.ts#L259.

[image]

And there is a sample code of [`websockets.ts`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/event-hubs/samples/websockets.ts) for EventHubs, and it requires `@azure/event-hubs` version `next` in its [`package.json`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/event-hubs/samples/package.json#L31). I think you just need to use [`WebSocket`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) in browser instead of `WebSocket` from `import WebSocket from "ws";` in the sample, then you could make it works in browser.

Comment: A small update to this answer
- You no longer need the `next` version of the `@azure/event-hubs` package. These features are available on the latest version since Jan 2020
- The sample link provided above is broken as the code got moved around. You can refer to https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/%40azure/event-hubs_5.2.1/sdk/eventhub/event-hubs/samples/javascript/websockets.js instead

Comment: example link is broken